# Why does the print function only execute once

Tags: go

Why does the print function in this code only execute once?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    b := make([]byte, 10)
    s := *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&b))
    b[0] = 'A'
    fmt.Println(s)
    fmt.Println("www")
}
```

Comment: If by "the print function", you mean `fmt.Println`, it doesn't (only execute once). Try this in the Go Playground for instance: https://play.golang.org/p/2UPiTuO_2KG There is a major problem here though: your code is unsafe; it may malfunction badly, and will behave differently on different systems. Don't use `unsafe` at all unless you know exactly what you are doing (or are experimenting so as to learn what it does); don't count on it working until you know how to use `unsafe` safely. :-)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what led you to try this in the first place?

Comment: thx. I just want to try to convert the variable b into a string with zero-copy and suddenly found this problem, I am curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comments above, whether the above works (whatever "works" really means) or not, depends on vagaries of the underlying system.  (My second comment was wrong and I have deleted it.)  In normal code, avoid `unsafe`: you need to know a lot about what you are doing with it, to use `unsafe` safely.  Worse, even if you do know what you are doing, and use it safely today, things you do with it now might break in a future Go release.

I asked why you were trying this in the first place:

> I just want to try to convert the variable b into a string with zero-copy ...

In this case, since **you** are *creating* `b`, you can just create it as a string in the first place.

More generally, there is an outstanding feature request for this.  See [(closed) issue 25484](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/25484) and still-open [issue 19367](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19367).  I think it unlikely that these will be adopted for Go version 1.

Note that if you do make a string header that grants access to the slice data, the underlying bytes in the string are *not* read-only, unlike normal Go strings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will avoid using unsafe in the code.